# Why does SPUtility.Redirect throw a thread abort exception

Tags: development, redirect

Wherever I use SPUtility.Redirect in my code it works ok for the user but i see a thread abort exception in the ULS logs, the message starts with:

"ExceptionType: 'ThreadAbortException' ExceptionMessage: 'Thread was being aborted.')"

Then a few lines later in ULS i see a host of request not disposed entries starting wtih:

"An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread"

I have seen other poeple reporting the ThreadAbortException on the internet, but no one has been able to explain why this happens, or how to use SPUtility.Redirect in such a way that the exception isn't thrown. Whilst Response.Redirect(url,false) doesn't raise an exception, i still see the entries reporting that the SPRequest wasn't disposed properly.
Hope you can help

Answer (score 5):

There's an answer on [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/fa58383d-4340-46b6-b168-d3710d7e2c6f) which explains it pretty well:

> Hello!
>
> When request is being redirected, the HttpResponse.End() method
>   is called. The given method, in turn, calls
>
> `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(new HttpApplication.CancelModuleException(false));`
>
> The `Thread.Abort` method raises `ThreadAbortException` in the thread where it is invoked to begin
>   the process of terminating the thread. I mentioned about that in my
>   [blog post](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2011/08/sharepoint-how-to-use-splongoperation/). So it's normal behavior.
>
> Try to use `SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse` when calling `SPUtility.Redirect()`.

Comment: Thank you for this, the correct solution and an explanation of the issue. I couldn't ask for more.

Edit: I know this is just pointing to another article but Google brought me here.